# MVC5 - Unable to create two models from different sources and insert records in database

Tags: asp.net-mvc-5

I'll try to be specific, to avoid be misunderstood.
I have a "*Master Detail*" in which I can add perceptions and deductions, select an employee, save the roster and rosterdetail in a database.
The roster saves the general information, and the rosterdetail saves each deduction and perception. 
The problem: When I try to save perceptions and deductions I get: Error: **An error occurred while updating the entries. See the inner exception for details.**
If I save only Perceptions it works, if i save only deductions it works. But both doesn't works.

Here is the complete code of the method Post:

```
[HttpPost]
    public ActionResult NewRoster(RosterView rosterView){
        rosterView = Session["rosterView"] as RosterView;
        //(Validations)
        var employeeID = Request["EmployeeID"].ToString();
        if (employeeID.Equals("")){
            ViewEmployee();
            ViewBag.Error = "Debe seleccionar un empleado";
            return View(rosterView);}
        var employee = db.Employees.Find(employeeID);
        if (employee.Equals("")){
            ViewEmployee();
            ViewBag.Error = "El empleado no existe";
            return View(rosterView);}
        if (rosterView.Perceptions.Count == 0){
            ViewEmployee();
            ViewBag.Error = "Debe ingresar una percepción";
            return View(rosterView);}
        if (rosterView.Deductions.Count == 0){
            ViewEmployee();
            ViewBag.Error = "Debe ingresar una deducción";
            return View(rosterView);}
        //(End Validations)

        //(Start the transaction)
        string rosterID = Guid.NewGuid().ToString();
        using (var transaction = db.Database.BeginTransaction()){
            try{
                var roster = new Roster
                {
                    RosterID = rosterID,
                    EmployeeID = employeeID,
                    RosterDate = DateTime.Now,
                    LastRosterDate = DateTime.Now,
                    StartRosterDate = DateTime.Now,
                    RosterStatus = RosterStatus.Created
                };
                db.Rosters.Add(roster);
                db.SaveChanges();

                string rosterDetailID = Guid.NewGuid().ToString();

                //(THIS WORKS BY ITSELF BUT NOT WITH THE SECOND ↓ FOREACH)
                foreach (var p in rosterView.Perceptions){
                    var rosterDetail = new RosterDetail(){
                        RosterDetailID = rosterDetailID,
                        RosterID = rosterID,
                        ID = p.PerceptionID,
                        Concept = p.Concepto,
                        Amount = p.AmountE,
                        AmountE = p.AmountG,
                        Key = p.PerceptionKey};
                    db.RosterDetails.Add(rosterDetail);
                    db.SaveChanges();
                }

                //(THIS WORKS BY ITSELF BUT NOT WITH THE FIRST ↑ FOREACH)
                foreach (var d in rosterView.Deductions)
                {
                    var rosterDetaild = new RosterDetail()
                    {
                        RosterDetailID = rosterDetailID,
                        RosterID = rosterID,
                        ID = d.DeductionID,
                        Concept = d.DeductionConcept,
                        Amount = d.Amount,
                        AmountE = 0,
                        Key = d.DeductionKey};
                    db.RosterDetails.Add(rosterDetaild);
                    db.SaveChanges();}}
            catch (Exception ex){
                transaction.Rollback();
                ViewBag.Error = "Error: " + ex.Message;
                ViewEmployee();
                return View(rosterView);}
            transaction.Commit();}

        ViewBag.Message = string.Format("La nómina se guardó correctamente ", rosterID);
        ViewEmployee();
        rosterView = new RosterView();
        rosterView.Employee = new Employee();
        rosterView.Perceptions = new List<PerceptionOrder>();
        rosterView.Deductions = new List<DeductionOrder>();
        Session["rosterView"] = rosterView;
        return View(rosterView);}
```

**Solution**
Show the InnerException

[image: Read the error]

... I was reusing the primary key

Comment: Well, what are the details in the inner exception?

Comment: It has never happened to you that it only exposes the subject with someone else, a single comment can solve a doubt of days? You just did that, I edited the answer for the solution.